# Назначение RxJava, RxAndroid

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Для чего нужны библиотеки RxJava и RxAndroid? Где их применяют?

Comment: Почитайте это http://habrahabr.ru/post/265269/ В один ответ такие вещи не впихнуть

Comment: @Suvitruf, спасибо, хорошая статья.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**RxJava** - либа для обработки событий как последовательностей. Надстройка над паттерном "наблюдатель", умеет по-всякому преобразовывать последовательности событий и так далее. Либу можно заюзать где угодно, но особо полезна когда нужно делать всякие сложные преобразования над событиями, типа смешать, сгруппировать, фильтровать, ограничивать и т.п.

**RxAndroid** - либа на базе RxJava, содержит всякие штуки для андроида типа шедулера для гуевого потока.

Всякая логика типа "получать символы в текстбоксах от юзера, отправлять запросы к серверу в другом потоке, но не слишком часто, с какой-то задержкой, обновлять интерфейс" пишутся на этих либах в пару строк, без гемороя с кучей служебного кода.

Comment: А какие есть еще библиотеки на подобие этих ? И почему сейчас все "молятся" на реактивное программирование в Андроиде?

Comment: Либа пошла из дотнетной Rx которую долго разрабатывали и вылизывали. Альтернативы как-бы особо не нужны, потому что в Rx* все очень круто. :)) Я б не сказал что народ как-то осбо молится, просто задачи которые раньше были сложными стали простыми. Юзать или нет - зависит от того есть ли у вас эти сложные задачи с потоками событий :)

Comment: Про проблему поворота девайса при загрузке данных с сервера знаете ? Это с помощью Rx решается ?

Comment: Я не в теме​ :)

Comment: Rx позволяет обойти callback-hell, возникающий чаще всего как раз при разработке пользовательских интерфейсов.

Comment: на ютюбе куча презентаций. Мобиус/Яндекс где спикеры очень простым языком объясняют что такое Rx на примере андроида и почему он настолько прекрасен

Answer (score 0):

RxJava это набор инструментов, которые помогут написать красивый, но более простой код. Он обладает интуитивностью, расширяемостью, декларативностью, возможностью компоновки и конвертируемостью. На эту тему нашла полезную [статью](https://redwerk.com/blog/5-reasons-love-rxjava), которая как раз раскрывает назначение этой Java библиотеки.

Comment: весьма абстрактно ))